# Unable to change view in content and structure

Tags: site-settings, content-and-structure

I want to access all the files checked out in a site collection, for which the best way is to do it through Ste action>>sites settings>>content and structure.

I am unable to change the view to `Checked Out to Me` and i always see default view. I am a site collection admin, so permissions cant be an issue.

Kindly help.

Comment: what is your browser? and is jquery enabled in your site collection masterpage?

Comment: @Hameds i am using IE8 , 32 Bit. How do i check if jquey is enabled in site collection master page. I guess it is enabled.

Comment: to check if jQuery is enabled just see page source in ie and look for jQuery reference. we had similar problem in content and structure with jQuery. remove jQuery reference and check again to see if problem resolved. if that was the case, then I can tell a workaround for this

Comment: @Hameds Thank you for your response. I don't think that can be an issue because i created a new site collection with default master page but i am still getting the facing the same issue.